# Почему не инжектится переменная Dagger2

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger2, dagger

Вот сделал имплементацию дагера и вроде как все работет, вот только context переменная не хочет инжектиться

Вот так я хочу ее получить в своем baseactivity

```
abstract class SunshineBaseActivity: AppCompatActivity(), IScreenNavigator
{
@Inject lateinit var mContext: Context
....//
}
```

Теперь вот мой application

```
class SunshineApp: Application()
{
companion object
{
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SunshineApp
    {
        return context.applicationContext as SunshineApp
    }
}

val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).
networkModule(NetworkModule()).build()
}

override fun onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate()
    appComponent.inject(this)
}
}
```

Сам Context я получаю в AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule(val app: SunshineApp)
{
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApp() = app

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideContext(): Context
{
    return app
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun getLayoutInflater(app: SunshineApp): LayoutInflater
{
    return LayoutInflater.from(app)
}
}
```

Что сделал не так?

**ПРАВКА**

Как мне казалось, что вот этот метод

```
override fun onCreate()
{
super.onCreate()
appComponent.inject(this)
}
```

который указан в этом классе

```
class SunshineApp: Application()
```

как раз и делает инжект для всего дагера, и мне не нужно будет вызывать инжект в каждом активити. Но нет, получается так, что нужно

Немного поменял структуру, теперь выглядит так

```
abstract class SunshineBaseActivity: AppCompatActivity(), IScreenNavigator
{
@Inject lateinit var mContext: Context

private val mComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
    SunshineApp.getInstance(this).appComponent
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mComponent.inject(this)
..///
}

..///

}
```

И `Application` выглядит так

```
class SunshineApp: Application()
{
companion object
{
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SunshineApp
    {
        return context.applicationContext as SunshineApp
    }
}

val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).networkModule(NetworkModule()).build()
}
}
```

И вроде все работает, но только странно получается, что если мне нужно инжектнуть контекст в другом активити которое наследуется от `SunshineBaseActivity` например `PreviewActivity : SunshineBaseActivity` то я не могу в `inject()`  как параметр передать `this`

Кстати вот мой компонент

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = [(AppModule::class), (NetworkModule::class), 
(DrawerModule::class)])
interface AppComponent
{
fun inject(app: SunshineBaseActivity)
fun plus(matchesModule: PreviewModule): PreviewComponent
}
```

Так вот не могу я передать `this` потому , что он хочет получить `SunshineBaseActivity` и странно получается то, что он как будто не видит, что `PreviewActivity` является наследником.

Все работает только если в компонент добавить еще одну строчку, вот так

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = [(AppModule::class), (NetworkModule::class), 
(DrawerModule::class)])
interface AppComponent
{
fun inject(app: SunshineBaseActivity)
fun inject(app: PreviewActivity)
fun plus(matchesModule: PreviewModule): PreviewComponent
}
```

Но как то странно выходит... Теперь для каждого нового активити в котором мне нужно использовать `AppModule` прийдется добавлять строчку с инжектом в компонент? Или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Не видно вызова appCompanent.inject() в реализациях активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил правку в вопрос. Вроде немного разобрался , но все равно вопрос остался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppComponent#inject(this)` надо явно вызывать в каждой конкретной реализации к-л класса. Т.е., если у вас есть базовый абстрактный класс, то в нём `inject()` вызывать не надо, а вот во всех его наследниках надо. В т.ч. наследниках не абстрактных классов.

Т.е. правило - `inject()` надо вызывать для всех неабстрактных классов для которых инъекции осуществляются не через конструктор. Только так Dagger сможет сгенерировать код для инъекций.

---

Если бы использовалась инъекция через конструктор, то вызывать `AppComponent#inject(this)` нигде не было бы надо, но для каждого неабстрактного класса надо было бы написать `@Provides` метод.

Т.к. активити/фрагменты/сервисы создаются системой и их конструкторы использовать нельзя, то надо вызывать `AppComponent#inject(this)` в каждом конкретном классе.

Comment: Первое, что хотел уточнить это - почему не нужно вызывать инжект для базового абстрактного класса, если есть допустим у меня `NavigationDrawer` и его удобнее инжектнуть в базовый класс и использовать во всех активити наследниках... В таком случае нужен инжект для базового абстрактного класса, верно ведь? И второе, значит если я вас правильно понял, то для каждого активити в конмоненте нужно написать инжект со нужным параметром, так?

Comment: Вы можете инъектить что-то в абстрактные классы, помечая поля/сеттеры `@Inject`, но `Dagger` не будет генерить код для непосредственной инъекции в классы, экземпляры коих невозможно создать. Так что да - в компоненте надо по  `inject` методу на каждую активити, коя раширяет базовую, в коей что-то инъектится. Иначе поля будут `null`, ибо `Dagger` не сгенерит код для этих классов.

Comment: Ну а насчет первого? Я прав или нет? Я так понял ваш комментарий касался второго вопроса , насчет нужно ли инжект указывать для все расширяющих. Тут все ясно теперь. Но насчет первого что?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko,  на самом деле я на первый вопрос отвечал) А он, заодно, и на второй ответом является)) Попробую иначе - можно поля `@Inject` пометить в абстрактном классе. В наследниках эти поля переопределять не нужно и не нужно помечать их аннотацией. Главное помнить, что, т.к. инъекция конкретных экземпляров зависимостей в поля будет происходить в конкретных классах, а не в базовом, то, если провайдится не синглтон, то в каждой конкретной активити будет свой экземпляр класса-зависимости. `почему не нужно вызывать инжект для базового абстрактного класса` - его не не нужно, но нельзя.

Comment: А вот еще не совсем по теме, но раз уже начали) Хотел спросить в чем разница получения `App` в этих двух подходов https://ideone.com/1R1unP и https://ideone.com/767grm мне кажется что первый более верный, так как какой смысл передавать контекст?

Comment: Смысла во втором я тоже не вижу - если у нас есть контекст где-то - то получить applicationContext и скастовать его к Application ничто не мешает прямо на месте. Засим первый способ верный, а второй - странное извращение) Таково моё мнение)

Comment: Да мне тоже так кажется, но дело в том, что я уже 2 й раз в статьях по имплементации даггера, нахожу именно такой подход и не пойму в чем смысл...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, возможно, так нужно если приложение в нескольких процессах работает. Т.е. есть несколько экземпляров класса `Application`